# CA Siteminder Installation - "super user could not be saved in the policy store"

Tags: windows-xp, installation, ldap

Roadblock during CA SiteMinder Policy Server installation. I've moved past various other LDAP credential related errors, but haven't been able to find any information on this one, whatsoever.

What do I need to do in order to move past this error?

Windows XP installation, 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try running through smldapsetup and import the base objects:

```
smldapsetup reg -h<host> -p<port> -d<admindn> -w<adminpw> -r<root> -f<ldif> [-t<tool>] [-ssl<1|0> -c<certdb>] [-v]
```

Example:

1. `smldapsetup reg -h10.10.10.10 -p11411 -d"cn=directory manager" -wpassword -rdc=netegrity,dc=com`
2. `smldapsetup ldgen -ftest.txt` (This command generates the test.txt file)
3. `smldapsetup ldmod -ftest.txt` (This command uses the test.txt file that was generated in step 2.)

Import SM Objects:

```
smobjimport -i<input_filename> [-f] [-c -d<adminname> -w<adminpw>] [-k] [-u] [-m] [-r] [-4] [-l] [-v] [-t] [-a1] [-a2]
```

Example:

1. `smobjimport -f -i"C:\Program Files\Netegrity\SiteMinder\Db\SMdif\smpolicy.smdif" -v smobjimport.log`